# How do I animate a rectangle in pygame to move from side to side forever?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
#this game is called stack power tower

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
x = 50
y = 50
height = 40
width = 100
run = True
passs = True
while run:
    def animate(passs, x, y, height, width):
        while passs:
            if x <= vel:
                x+=vel
                pygame.draw.rect(x, y, (255, 0, 0),height, width)
                pygame.fill()
            elif x >= 500-vel:
                x-=vel
                pygame.draw.rect(x, y, (255, 0, 0), height, width)
                pygame.fill()
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_Space]:
        passs=False
    else:
        animate(passs, x, y, height, width)
```

I do not understand why my code is not working. Nothing pops up on the pygame window. I am trying to animate the rectangle to move from x-pos to new x-pos, continuously back and forth, not in the y-direction. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am also new to pygame and stackoverflow, so if you have any tips of how I should reformat or reword the question or code to be clearer that would be helpful for future questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many things wrong with your code, it is hard to say where to start.

First, you defined a function again and again in a loop, which is not efficient

Second, you ran an unneeded while loop without an exit condition

Third, you passed incorrect arguments to the `draw.rect()` function

Fourth, all your conditionals are incorrect

Fifth, `pygame.fill()` is not a function.

Sixth, Dont run `time.Delay`, use `clock.tick(60)`.

Seventh, you did not update the screen.

Here is the correct code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
x = 50
y = 50
height = 40
width = 100
run = True
vel = 10
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
direction = 'Right'

def animate(x, y, height, width, direction):
    if x < 0:
        direction = 'Right'

    elif x > 500:
        direction = 'Left'

    if direction == 'Right':
        x += vel

    elif direction == 'Left':
        x -= vel

    pygame.draw.rect(dis, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height))

    return x, direction

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    dis.fill((0, 0, 0))


    x, direction = animate(x, y, height, width, direction)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Please learn more about python and pygame before you go on here asking for help.

The [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) are very useful.

Comment: thanks. I looked at the docs and you are right, my code was really bad. ill look at the docs and research a bit more before asking again. :)

Comment: While youre at it, please verify my answer.

Comment: your answer is fine, I just edited one of the elif statements to stop the block from disappearing of  the screen